# Euler product for sum of multiplicative function times log

Tags: analytic-number-theory, euler-product

Let $g$ be a multiplicative function. [Iwaniec and Fouvry](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa79/aa7935.pdf) claim the following identity on p. 273, identity (7.19). Why is this Euler product identity true?

$$-\sum_n \mu(n)g(n)\log n = \prod_{p} (1-g(p))(1-p^{-1})^{-1}$$

Even the case $g(n)=1/n$ is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

$$F(s) = \prod_p \frac{1-g(p)p^{-s}}{1-p^{-1} p^{-s}} = \sum_n \frac{n^{-s}}{n} \sum_m \mu(m) g(m) m^{-s} = \sum_n n^{-s} \sum_{d | n} \mu(d) g(d) \frac{d}{n}$$
but we are told that for $s = 0$ it is also equal to :
$$F(0) = -\sum_n \ln n \mu(n) g(n) $$

and in your link, $\mu(d) g(p)$ seems to be a particular case corresponding to $$\sum_{d | n} \mu(d) g(d) \frac{n}{d} = -\mu(n) \ln(n) g(n)$$

writing $G(s) = \sum \mu(n) g(n) n^{-s}$ we get that $G'(s) = -\sum \ln n \mu(n) g(n) n^{-s}$ so that if $\sum_{d | n} \mu(d) g(d) \frac{n}{d} = -\mu(n) \ln(n) g(n)$ it means $G(s) \zeta(s+1) = G'(s)$

Comment: That isn't true - just looking at $n$ prime makes $g$ take weird negative values. As far as I can tell the link assumes only some weak growth conditions on $g$.

Comment: to add $p^{-s}$ in the euler product and let $s$ tend to $0$ is perfectly rigorous because of the abscissa of convergence of Dirichlet series, and the fact that $g$ is multiplicative (or at least $\mu(n) g(n)$ )

Comment: I agree that your calculation is reasonable, however it's possible for two L-functions to take the same value at the same point without having the same coefficients. The identity you give completely determines $g$ but the paper proves it for some family of nice $g$. I'm starting to think that the identity is not true - any idea what the right Euler product should be?

Comment: if $g(n) \mu(n)$ is multiplicative, then $-\ln n g(n) \mu(n)$ is not, so no idea.